# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error

Ive stared to learn Javascript, im trying to create a calculator, which just multiplies 2 numbers, i get this error in my browser console.
Can anybody help?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calc</title>
    <style>#result{position: relative; top: 5px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="first"> *
    <input type="number" id="second">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="result" value="Check out" onclick="res()"></input> <span id="span"></span> 
    <script>
        function res() {
            var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("second").value;
            var span = document.getElementById("span");
            if(a != 0 && b !=0) {
                span.innerHTML = a * b;
            }
            if(a = 0 ||  b = 0) {
                span.innerHTML = "0"; // I know browser can do it automatically without 21 and 22 strings but i need that it works this way.  
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `==` is for equality comparison, you realize it?

Comment: my mistake, thnx i thought its cuz of ||

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are going to do any math with text input, you have to convert them to a number. You can use `parseInt(num, 10)` or `parseFloat(num)`.

Secondly, in one of your if-statements, you are not actually comparing the variables `a` and `b`, but assigning `0` to them. Use two equal signs `==` to compare variables.

Thirdly, you could just check for whether they are numbers instead using `isNaN(num)`. Doing so would eliminate the first if-statement.

```js
function res() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
  var span = document.getElementById("span");
  
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    span.innerHTML = "0";
  }
  else {
    span.innerHTML = a * b;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="first">*
<input type="number" id="second">
<br>
<input type="submit" id="result" value="Check out" onclick="res()"></input> <span id="span"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

check here your corrected code

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Calc</title>
    <style>#result{position: relative; top: 5px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="first"> *
    <input type="number" id="second">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="result" value="Check out" onclick="res()"></input> <span id="span"></span> 
    <script>
        function res() {
            var a = document.getElementById("first").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("second").value;
            var span = document.getElementById("span");
            if(a != 0 && b !=0) {
                span.innerHTML = a * b;
            }
            if(a == 0 ||  b == 0) {
                span.innerHTML = "0"; // I know browser can do it automatically without 21 and 22 strings but i need that it works this way.  
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```